# Calculating the mode/median/most frequent observation in categorical variables in SQL impala

Tags: sql, frequency, impala, median

I would like to calculate the mode/median or better, most frequent observation of a categorical variable within my query.
E.g, if the variable has the following string values:
dog, dog, dog, cat, cat and I want to get dog since its 3 vs 2.
Is there any function that does that? I tried APPX_MEDIAN() but it only returns the first 10 characters as median and I do not want that.
Also, I would like to get the most frequent observation with respect to date if there is a tie-break.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the most frequent observation is `mode` and you can calculate it like this.

Single value mode can be calculated like this on a value column. Get the count and pick up row with max count.

```
select count(*),value from mytable group by value order by 1 desc limit 1
```

now, in case you have multiple modes, you need to join back to the main table to find all matches.

```
select orig.value from
(select count(*) c, value v from mytable) orig
join (select count(*) cmode from mytable group by value order by 1 desc limit 1) cmode
ON orig.c= cmode.cmode
```

This will get all count of values and then match them based on count. Now, if one value of count matches to max count, you will get 1 row, if you have two  value counts matches to max count, you will get 2 rows and so on.

Calculation of `median` is little tricky - and it will give you middle value. And its not most frequent one.